# Some examples of errors in ESL?

Tags: machine-learning, error, supervised-learning

I am reading the book [*The Elements of Statistical Learning*](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) (Hastie *et al*, chapter 7)  and I am confused about the different kinds of errors mentioned in the book

1. Test error $$Err_\tau=E(L(y, \hat{f}(X)|\tau))$$
2. Expected prediction error $$Err=E(L(y, \hat{f}(X)))=E[Err_\tau]$$
3. Training error: $$\bar{err}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}L(y_i,\hat{f}(x_i))$$
4. In sample error: $$Err_{in}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}E_{Y^0}[L(Y_i^0,\hat{f}(x_i))]$$
5. Extra sample error: $$Err_\tau=E_{X^0,Y^0}(L(Y^0, \hat{f}(X^0)|\tau))$$

Can anyone give some idea to well understand these and some simple examples would be appreciated?

Comment: 3 is just a different representation of 2. 1 is just 2 or 3 applied over a testing set. E in 2 or 1 is the average illustrated in 3. Thus, the comparison reduces to 1 or 2 or 3 and 4 and 5. I am not sure about Y^0 in 4 and 5 !